# Rename "post" to "article" throughout the admin back end

Tags: posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to change 'Posts' to be 'Portfolio' is the WP backend?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15840/is-there-a-way-to-change-posts-to-be-portfolio-is-the-wp-backend)

Is there a way to accomplish this by the functions.php file ?

I tried:

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_post_to_article'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'change_post_to_article'  );

function change_post_to_article( $translated ) {

   $translated = str_ireplace(  'Post',  'Article',  $translated );

   return $translated;
```

}

but it does not change all the entries for "post". I still have "Post tags" for example.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I once wrote [how to change the default taxonomy labels](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4182/can-the-default-post-tags-taxonomy-be-renamed), like *"Post Tags"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of this question:

[How to rename default posts-type Posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15840/is-there-a-way-to-change-posts-to-be-portfolio-is-the-wp-backend/15848#15848)

Comment: Thank you and sorry for not having found it by myself

Comment: @mirko, actually I'm not sure it's a complete duplicate - I don't know if the plugin mentioned handles taxonomies - you'll need to check that out

Comment: There is a snippet in one of the answers which does handle everything ;)